# How do I show the selected value of select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am trying to set the value dynamically to my combobox on which I have applied select2 jQuery class. After applying code it sets the value to that combobox; but it still says "Select one". 
Can anyone help me to show the selected value? Please.

**HTML**:

```
<select id="cmboDemo">
 <option value="">Select one</option>
 <option value="Bob">Bob</option>
 <option value="Scott">Scott</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#cmboDemo").select2();
//....
$("#cmboDemo").val("Scott");
...//
```

In result **scott** is selected but combobox shows "**Select one**".

Comment: It changes though? https://jsfiddle.net/brz61j2y/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `$("#cmboDemo").select2();`

and use  the second one only:

```
$("#cmboDemo").val("Scott");
```

Comment: I have used this code also. But still it's not working !

Comment: No mate. Still its doesn't work. I think there is problem with some **css** which came with **select2.js**

Comment: It works absolutely fine without that. but I want to use that **select2** , which gives me scroll and type effect.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jtf7gkfw/1/ check that External Resources and replace yours with that

Answer (score 0):

By using **select2.js** some additional layers of **css** are overlapped actual combo-box. By using all above code the value is set to select box; but because of that upper style layer it shows first value. i.e Select one.
So by changing that upper layer's **text** will fixed the problem.

This is the final outcome:

```
$("#select2-cmboDemo-container").text("Scott");
```

Thanks.